# Spring boot Hibernate batch insert

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

application.property:

```
  jpa:
properties:
  hibernate:
    order_inserts: true
    order_updates: true
    batch_versioned_data: true
    jdbc:
      batch_size: 10
database: postgresql
hibernate:
  ddl-auto: create-drop
```

logging:
level:
org:
hibernate:
SQL: DEBUG

Entity Product class:

```
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private Long id;
private String name;
private String description;
private LocalDateTime createdDate;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
private List<ProductPrice> pricesList;
@ManyToOne
private User user;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
private List<ProductLink> productLinks;

public Product(String name, String description, LocalDateTime createdDate, User user) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
    this.user = user;
}
```

}

Entity ProductLink class:

```
public class ProductLink {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private Long id;
private String link;
@ManyToOne
private Product product;

public ProductLink(String link, Product product){
    this.product = product;
    this.link = link;
}
```

}

Entity ProductPrice class:

```
public class ProductPrice {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private Long id;
private String storeName;
private String price;
private LocalDateTime updatedDate;
@ManyToOne
private Product product;

public ProductPrice(String storeName, String price, LocalDateTime updatedDate, Product product) {
    this.product = product;
    this.storeName = storeName;
    this.price = price;
    this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
}
```

}

Repository, same for the other

```
    @Repository
public interface ProductLinkRepository extends JpaRepository<ProductLink, Long> {
}
```

I want to use Hibernate batch insert, but that doesn't Work, i only have multiple insert query in console (One insert for one ProductLink, ProductPrice)

Save method:

```
        Product product = new Product(productDto.getName(), productDto.getDescription(), LocalDateTime.now(), user);
    Product save = productRepository.save(product);
    List<ProductLink> productLinks = new ArrayList<>();
    List<ProductPrice> pricesList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ProductLinksDto productLink : productDto.getProductLinks()) {
        if (!productLink.getLink().isEmpty()) {
            URL url = new URL(productLink.getLink());
            storeParser = new StoreParser(url);
            productLinks.add(new ProductLink(productLink.getLink(), save));
            pricesList.add(new ProductPrice(url.getHost(), storeParser.getPrice(), LocalDateTime.now(), save));
        }
    }

    productPriceRepository.saveAll(pricesList);
    productLinkRepository.saveAll(productLinks);
```